# Minimum number of steps required to visit every "special" point on a grid

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star, traveling-salesman

I am stuck at this problem:

---

Suppose we have the following **m by n** grid configuration (or matrix) **G** over the alphabet **{0,X,Y}**

**G=

0 0 X .. X

0 0 X .. 0

X Y 0 .. X

:  :  :      :

0 X 0 .. 0**

Find a good **lower bound** on the **minimal** number of steps required for **Y** to visit each of the **X**'s on the grid (I.e.each of the **X**'s in the matrix) at least once where **Y** can move **left**, **right**, **up** and **down** one *cell* at a time?

(The **Y** and the **X**'s in the grid **G** were arbitrarily placed, The **Y** and the **X**'s can be anywhere on the matrix, Also the number of the **X**'s on the matrix was arbitrary and there must be **exactly** one **Y** on the matrix).

---

Surely there is no some kind of mathematical formula that can give the exact number of steps (Since it is a TSP problem).

But how can we find a **sufficiently** **tight lower bound** for the actual number of steps (that is relatively easy to calculate using an algorithm, for example)?

I've seen what was suggested on:

[Using A* to solve Travelling Salesman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453477/using-a-to-solve-travelling-salesman)

And it was suggested there that the total cost of the **minimum spanning tree** can be a good lower bound for TSP problems.

But in contrast to the problem there, Here, In this problem, We are **not** **required** to visit **each** **of the points** on the grid, But we are **required** to visit **each of the "special" points** on the grid at least once and to get to them **we may need to visit some "non-special" points** on the grid, So I do not know how the **minimum spanning tree** looks like for this problem (and maybe how to adjust Kruskal's algorithm to find it).

(Note: I've encountered this problem while trying to figure out a heuristic for **A*** grid search that calculates a path for **Y** that must visit each of the **X**'s on the grid at least once)

Thanks for any hint or help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, a tight lower bound on the objective of the described problem is demanded. Such a bound is in fact the minimum spanning tree of the instance; the distances would be the pairwise shortest paths between the `X` and `Y` node (which in this case are some discrete Euklidean distances). The tightness of the bound can be seen considering an instance which looks like

```
YXXXXX...X
```

where the weight of the spanning tree (namely the number of nodes to visit minus one) matches the weight of the shortest path from `Y` to the rightmost `X` node. In total, Kruskal's algorithm does not need to be modified to calculate the minimum spanning tree.

Comment: But what about the points on the grid that are not required to be visited? Do they need some kind of special treatment? Am I supposed to include them in the **minimum spanning tree**?

Comment: Conceptually, the intermediate nodes can be removed from the problem once the distances for each pairs of `X` and `Y` nodes have been precalculated.